# How to pass $(this) as a parameter to another function in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, parameters

is there a way to pass `$(this)` to another function in jQuery?

This is what I've got but it won't work:

```
$(function() {

  $('[id$=price]').change(function() {
    var price = $(this).val();
    var quantity = $(this).closest('.fields').find('[id$=quantity]').val();     
    recalculate_subtotal($(this));
  });

  $('[id$=quantity]').change(function() {
    var quantity = $(this).val();
    var price = $(this).closest('.fields').find('[id$=price]').val();           
    recalculate_subtotal($(this));      
  });

  function recalculate_subtotal(element) {
    $(element).closest('.fields').find('#Subtotal').val(price * quantity);      
  }

});
```

(The last function is the one I want to get $(this) into.)

Thanks for any help and apologies. I am new to jQuery!

Comment: This doesn't look wrong really.. shouldn't need the `$()` around `element` though. Are you getting an error?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

That *will* work fine, although one theing to note is that if you're passing the jQuery object (`$(this)`) you dont need to wrap it again in `$()`:

```
$('[id$=price]').change(function() {
    var price = $(this).val();
    var quantity = $(this).closest('.fields').find('[id$=quantity]').val();     
    recalculate_subtotal($(this));
})


function recalculate_subtotal($element) {
    $element.closest('.fields').find('#Subtotal').val(price * quantity);      
}
```

Comment: I also tend to name variable containing jQuery collections starting with a `$`, as in `$element`.  I think it helps.

Comment: Yes - that's a neat naming convention.

Comment: @ExplosionPills - I totally agree. All my jQuery vars are prefixed $.

Comment: @Tintin81 - look at the comments on this answer, take note. Its very helpful for you to prefix variables which represent jquery objects with a `$` so you know when to wrap in `$()` and when not to. I'll update my answer to demonstrate this.

Answer (score 2):

You're almost there - get rid of the $() around your element variable:

```
function recalculate_subtotal(element) {
    element.closest('.fields').find('#Subtotal').val(price * quantity);      
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
$.fn.recalculate_subtotal = function () {
    element = $(this);   // you will get $(this) here
    $(element).closest('.fields').find('#Subtotal').val(price * quantity);      
}

$('#AnyElement').recalculate_subtotal(){
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are already passing $(this) you just need to change this:

```
function recalculate_subtotal(element) {
    element.closest('.fields').find('#Subtotal').val(price * quantity);      
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you are already passing the jQuery Object selector to your function you do not need the $() around the element.. this should do

```
function recalculate_subtotal(element) {
    element.closest('.fields').find('#Subtotal').val(price * quantity);      
}
```